# How to resolve mkcls taking up lots of memory and time for word alignment using GIZA++?

Tags: nlp, text-alignment, machine-translation, giza++

I am using the [GIZA++](http://code.google.com/p/giza-pp/) for aligning word from the bitexts from the [Europarl corpus](http://www.statmt.org/europarl/).

Before i train the alignment model using `GIZA++`, i need to use the [mkcls](http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/web/Software/mkcls.html) script to making classes that is necessary for Hidden Markov Model algorithm as such:

```
mkcls -n10 -pcorp.tok.low.src -Vcorp.tok.low.src.vcb.classes
```

I have tried it with a small size 1000 lines corpus and it works properly and completed in a few minutes. **Now i'm trying it on corpus with 1,500,000 lines and it's taking up 100% of one of the my CPU `(Six-Core AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 2431 × 12)`**

Before making the classes, i have taken the necessary step to tokenize, lower all upper cases and filter out lines with more than 40 words.

**Does anyone have similar experience on the `mkcls` for GIZA++? How is it solved? If anyone had done the same on the Europarl corpus, how long did it take you to run the `mkcls`?**

Comment: Okay now it's finished after 2 hours of `mkcls`...

Answer (score 0):

Because the `mkcls` script for `MOSES` and `GIZA++` isn't parallelized, and the number of sentences and words in the 1.5 million words in Europarl corpus, it takes around 1-2 hours to make the vocabulary classes.

the other pre-GIZA++ processing steps (viz. `plain2snt`, `snt2cooc`) takes much much lesser time and processing power.

Answer (score 0):

try **mgiza** (http://www.kyloo.net/software/doku.php/mgiza:overview ) which support multi-threading. It should significantly decrease amount of time needed to accomplish your task.

Comment: Still `mkcls` isn't parallelized and it takes very long for a large enough 2 mil sentence corpus. I've figured calling mkcls from `python` and then call it from `mprocess` did cut down the time.

Comment: hmm didn't know that. I deployed mgiza and everything was fast enough. You are right mkcls is the same in both programs ...